# Getting rendered HTML from a page loaded with clientside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that used to run a background script that would call an API for a website using the users session or cookie.

It'd simply perform a get request and then pull various image URLs from the page using Cheerio.

The owners of the site though have now changed how the pages work. On load, they call a JSON API, and the source of the page uses JavaScript to render the page.

The issues I have now is that when I call a get request, it simply gets the page source, rather than the rendered HTML.

Does anyone know how I can get the rendered HTML? I'd rather not open a tab with the page in chrome, grab the data with a content script and then close it (automatically of course) as there are hundreds of pages to go through, and that's quite intensive on CPU resources

Comment: Either use an iframe (in your background page) and a content script with `"all_frames:"true` or ideally call their API directly and extract the data (you may need to reverse-engineer their js on the page to understand what goes where).

Comment: Calling their API is fine, the problem is the image URLs are all signed, and somehow when the page is rendered, it generates a signed URL from the API data. Something I don't think I can replicate. As for the iframe, how would I do that and parse the HTML content from it on a background script?

Comment: Generation of the signed key may be very simple so you shouldn't give up without at least trying to reverse-engineer their page script which generates it. As for iframe, well, there should be examples around, this is pretty much a typical scenario (web page with a content script inside + background script + messaging) so I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: The code has been build, so its a lot of `function x(y)` etc.  I have by chance found that its putting the full URL into local storage when the page loads.  Guess I just need to figure out how that happens, and then go from there